# Как правильно употребляется глагол "сохраняются" в данном предложении, в единственном или множественнои числе?

Tags: точное-словоупотребление

Сохраняются круг покупателей, товары, порядок торговли и сроки представления отчетов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы выбрала ед. число: ***Сохраняется** круг покупателей, товары, порядок торговли и сроки представления отчетов.*

Выбору ед. числа способствуют следующие факторы:

1. Препозиция сказуемого.
2. Сочетание "сохраняются круг" в начале предложения очень некомфортно воспринимается на слух.
3. Пассивность неодушевленных предметов.
4. Можно подобрать обобщающее слово: сохраняется всё.

В пользу мн. числа при согласовании говорит только наличие некоторых существительных в форме мн. числа, но они находятся в середине предложения и не оказывают значительного влияния на восприятие предложения в целом.

Правило Розенталя
[§190. Согласование сказуемого с однородными подлежащими](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm#%D0%B7_08)